# How to show dialog from Expandble list adapter which is in an Activity Group

Tags: expandablelistview, android-datepicker

I am using an Activity Group which contain an Activity which is using a BaseExpandableListAdapter . It has 2 method  groupview and child view. In child view i want to use dialog boxes ( showDialog(DATE_PICKER) ) but code doesn't reach the method

public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this in childView.

Dialog dialog=new Dialog();

dialog.setTitle("Title");

dialog.show();